# Struggling to count down my text input with the value it is set at

Tags: javascript

trying to build a little countdown gym program. I'm trying to give the user the ability to input a value from the text input and when the click start it begins to count down from that number. I'm getting my value I set logging to the console but it isn't outputting back into the innerHTML??

thoughts?

```js
let startTimer;

// buttons
const start = document.getElementById('start');
const pause = document.getElementById('pause');
const reset = document.getElementById('reset');

start.addEventListener('click', initTimer);

function initTimer(){
    clearInterval(countDown)
    setInterval(countDown, 1000);
}

function countDown(){
    const work = document.getElementById('work');
    var workVal = work.value;
    work.innerHTML = workVal
    console.log(workVal)
    startTimer = workVal
    
    work.innerHTML = `${startTimer}`
    startTimer--
}
```

```html
<div class="timer">
    <div class="numb">
        <h1 class="timeNum"><input type='text' min="00" id="rounds" value="00">:<input type='text' min="00" id="work" value="00">:<input type='text' min="00"  id="rest" value="00">:<input type='text' min="00" id="breaks" value="00"></h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, my start button works fine, i was just hoping I could set the value in my text input and upon clicking the start button counting the text input down. I'm receiving the console logs with values set. just not let me output the value to innerHTML in the text input

Comment: You should probably set the initial value for `startTimer` inside the `initTimer()` function to be equal to `work.value` and then in the `countDown()` function do `work.value = startTimer` just before `startTimer--`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`.

then you need to move the counter outside, so you can pause/resume it dynamically.

the same way you should track rounds, and then start rest interval

```js
let startTimer;

// buttons
const start = document.getElementById('start');
const pause = document.getElementById('pause');
const resume = document.getElementById('resume');
const reset = document.getElementById('reset');


start.addEventListener('click', initTimer);
pause.addEventListener('click', pauseTimer);
resume.addEventListener('click', resumeTimer);
reset.addEventListener('click', resetTimer);

let countDownInterval, restInterval, breakInterval;

const work = document.getElementById('work');
const rounds = document.getElementById('rounds');
const rest = document.getElementById('rest');
const breaks = document.getElementById('breaks');

const status = document.getElementById('done');


function initTimer() {

  clearInterval(countDownInterval)
  countDownInterval = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
  status.innerText = '';
}

function pauseTimer() {
  clearInterval(countDownInterval);
}

function resumeTimer() {
  countDownInterval = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
}

function resetTimer() {
  clearInterval(countDownInterval);
  work.value = '00';
  status.innerText = '';
}

function countDown() {

  var workVal = work.value;

  startTimer = workVal;
  startTimer--;

  console.log(workVal)

  if (startTimer < 1) {
    // check rounds, start breaks etc.
    work.value = '00';
    clearInterval(countDownInterval);
    status.innerText = 'done';

  } else {
    work.value = startTimer;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="pause">pause</button>
<button id="resume">resume</button>
<button id="reset">reset</button>
<div class="timer">
  <div class="numb">
    <h1 class="timeNum">
      <input type='text' min="00" id="rounds" value="00">:
      <input type='text' min="00" id="work" value="00">:
      <input type='text' min="00" id="rest" value="00">:
      <input type='text' min="00" id="breaks" value="00"></h1>
  </div>
</div>
<h1 id="done"></h1>
```